# creating a controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, atom-editor

I am unable to create a controller.

followed this step

```
<?php

   class Blog extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    echo 'Hello World!';
}
  }
?>

 Saved the file to my application/controllers/blog.php
```

then it says

> PAGE  NOT FOUND

[image: opening index.php]
[image: after creating controller]
[image]

Comment: Make sure controller is Blog.php you may need to set name in your routes.php

Comment: yes the controller is blog.php

Comment: But is it like this Blog.php instead of this blog.php

Comment: thanks issue resolve it was of capital B

Comment: All controllers and library etch must start with a capital now in CI3 other wise get 404 on local and live server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was regarding naming of controller most tutorial suggested the controller file name coulb small but class name should Start with Capital
Here renaming the controller file-name with captial Blog solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is regarding the naming convention in Codeigniter. The naming convention is that, the name of the controller must be the same as the file name. It must also start with capital letter.So the name of your controller is Blog ,then the name of the file must be also Blog.php .

I hope this helps. ^_^